# How do I get dynamic height of view? (Xcode)

Tags: swift, xcode, height

The static height of my `view` is set to 30, but it's text content vary in length, expanding the height of the `view` accordingly. I have tried to get a hold of the height programatically using

```
ingredientViewOutlet.frame.height
```

But this only returns the static height of 30. How do I get ahold of the dynamic height of the `view`?

Comment: Are you sure the view is expanding? Probably is just Not clipping to bounds and the UILabel (or whatever other view you are using) containing the text is expanding inside your view.

Comment: Yes, I'm certain. I can see it expanding in accordance with the text content, but the `print(ingredientViewOutlet.frame.height)` remain the same. I have also tried `print(ingredientViewOutlet.bounds.size.height)` with the same result.

Comment: I am trying to research a solution. Seems like it may require calculating the constraint for the view aswell. Will let you know if I find anything.

Comment: Have you tried collecting ingredientViewOutlet.bounds.size.height AFTER the viewDidLoad? Try it in "viewDidAppear".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside:

```
    func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool){}
```

Add this:

```
    let height = ingredientViewOutlet.frame.height
```

This should let you get the 'dynamic' height of the view AFTER the view has already been loaded and adjusted to the screen.

Comment: WOOH! Thanks a bunch @DaWiseguy, that certainly solved the issue! Good thinking! :)

Comment: @tore No problem! I just got through working on a Swift 3 iOS project at work. So it's fresh on my mind. Don't forget to come back around and upvote the answer when you have enough rep ;)